# Facebook API limiting me to 50 results

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios8

I am developing an iOS app for a friend of mine who runs a photography Facebook page with hundreds of members who upload a photo every week according to the weekly theme.  I call out to the facebook API to grab all the albums from the facebook page when my app launches, and for months it was working fine and giving me back all four hundred albums or so, along with the album name and the first picture of every album.  Then a few weeks ago it stopped working and now limits me to 50 albums.  I have been using this graph path this entire time, i've never changed it...

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/180889155269546?fields=albums.limit(10000).fields(name,photos.limit(1).fields(picture))
```

I've googled and dug through the facebook API docs and can't find anything as to why i'm randomly being limited now to 50 results, when i used to get back all the results i needed for months.  Does anyone know what facebook changed with their API?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: If it changed then file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs .

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement paging to get all results: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

They´ve changed it a long time ago, so i guess it would be a bug if it still works with setting a very high limit like yours. Meaning, it´s intentional to only get 50 entries.